# Accented characters in filenames in zip archives

Tags: ruby, zip, filenames, diacritics

The RubyZip library is happy to let me create filenames with accented characters:

```
require 'zip/zip'

Zip::ZipFile.open("my.zip", Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) { |zipfile|
    zipfile.get_output_stream("Café.txt") { |f| f.puts "Hello from ZipFile" }
}
```

But they look corrupted in the resulting zip:

```
$ unzip -v my.zip 
Archive:  my.zip
Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
      19  Defl:N       21 -11% 2011-02-11 11:14 c49ac197  Caf??.txt
```

If I unzip the file on the same Linux system that created it, the filename is restored correctly, but can I trust these to work elsewhere or should I play it safe and dumb down the names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, I would always refrain from using non-ascii characters (which includes accented characters) in any filename -- especially one that's meant to be accessed programmatically, and especially within a compressed file.  Not only can it cause a hassle considering other languages that aren't so internationally-sensitive, but decompressors are notoriously bad at dealing with non-ascii characters.

Comment: Yup.  Turns out this isn't an issue with the ZIP format as such, but the way the contents are interpreted by various OSs and ZIP handling tools, so we've dumbed down the names.